# Gzip and Bzip uncompress with PHP

Tags: php, gzip, compression, bzip

How to identify, with PHP, if a compress file has more than one file compressed?

I got it with ZIP compress, but I didn't with Gzip and Bzip.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gzip and Bzip is used to compress a single file.
Offen this fil is tar archive which can have more files in it.